# If I reserve 5 Elastic IPs on AWS, do I get 500 free remaps?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

It's hard to understand from [Amazon EC2 Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/#Elastic_IP_Addresses) if 100 free remaps/month are per account or per Elastic IP address.
Any experience?

Comment: I agree that it's not clear from the documentation. I would assume that it's per account, otherwise you would simply allocate an EIP, do 100 remaps, then release the EIP, and allocate a new EIP, getting another 100 free remaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation lists:

```
$0.00 per Elastic IP address remap for the first 100 remaps per month
$0.10 per Elastic IP address remap for additional remaps over 100 per month
```

This applies to the AWS Account as a whole.